# Rails 4 many-to-many associations nightmare

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, many-to-many, associations

I'm trying to set up a `has_many :through` association between three models: `Trip`, `Location` and `LocationsTrip`, but the associations just don't seem to be picking each other up.

I set up my associations:

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :locations_trips
  has_many :locations, :through => :locations_trips

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations_trips, :allow_destroy => :true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations, :allow_destroy => :true
end

class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :locations_trips, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :trips, :through => :locations_trips
end

class LocationsTrip < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :locations
    belongs_to :trips
end
```

When I run `Trip.last.locations` in the Rails console I get

```
NameError: uninitialized constant Trip::Locations
```

so I've obviously missed something crucial, but I feel as if I've been through every similar answer on here and can't see where I'm going wrong.

It's probably worth mentioning I'm trying to set this up with `Trips` accepting nested attributes for `Locations` so in the `Trip` form partial I've got a `f.fields_for :locations do |builder|` etc, but when I load up the page I get the same `NameError` as before.

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd be massively grateful - I feel like I'm getting tunnel vision on this.

I'm using Ruby 2.1.2 and Rails 4.2.0.

Comment: Can you show the output of `tree your_app/app/models`..... ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're using plural names for the join table `belongs_to` associations. Try changing to:

```
class LocationsTrip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :location
  belongs_to :trip
end
```